# Spark SQL failed while reading table format OpenCSVSerde ClassNotFoundException Class org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde not found

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, pyspark

I am trying to load a hive table format SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde' to PySpark using below code.

> from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
>
> ent = sqlContext.sql("select * from temp.employee")

**Error:**

```
MetaException(message:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException Class org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde not found)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Table.getDeserializerFromMetaStore(Table.java:290)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Table.getDeserializer(Table.java:281)
```

I have tried adding Hive serde jars to Spark classpath as below

> spark.driver.extraClassPath=/usr/hdp/2.3.2.0-2950/hadoop/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/usr/hdp/2.3.2.0-2950/hadoop/lib/hive-serde-1.2.1.2.3.2.0-2950.jar
>
> spark.executor.extraClassPath=/usr/hdp/2.3.2.0-2950/hadoop/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/usr/hdp/2.3.2.0-2950/hadoop/lib/hive-serde-1.2.1.2.3.2.0-2950.jar

After adding above jars, the table reading went fine for this table but it is failing for other normal tables with below error.

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o38.sql.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hive/common/type/HiveIntervalYearMonth
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.primitive.PrimitiveObjectInspectorUtils.<clinit>(PrimitiveObjectInspectorUtils.java:228)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.typeinfo.TypeInfoUtils$TypeInfoParser.expect(TypeInfoUtils.java:341)
```

Is there something wrong in adding the jars to spark executor path?
How to resolve this?

Comment: I'm just guessing, but maybe the OpenCSVSerde jar you added was built for a newer version of Hive than the one you use. Do you face this problem regardless of the way of how you add the jar? https://github.com/ogrodnek/csv-serde recommends issuing `add jar path/to/csv-serde.jar;` as an HQL command before the actual query. Please also note that the jar should be available on all machines of the cluster.

Comment: I am able to run the query and access the data from Hive. The issue is when I try to access from Spark SQL